# Web Bookmark icon on the home screen, via app / play store?

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I have a web application which supports classic browsers as well as mobile browsers.

Most of my users seem to struggle with the concept of creating a bookmark to a URL and selecting "Add to home screen"
So they can get a nice icon that "feels" like a native app on the home screen or app draw of their mobile devices.

Is there a way I can simplify this process for them? or perhaps submit a native app to the app / play store that is nothing more than a shortcut anyway?

Or is a native webview the only solution?

Any suggestions you have would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the "add to homescreen bubble"  The following link will take you to how google does it.  I have never implemented and this solution only works for iOS from what I know.  But it may get you what you need

http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/

an example of the source code is here:

http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/source/browse/example/example.html?r=0699d12cfe8cc906accd66e7c49f3fd4fb10bad6

Good luck, wish I could be of more help.

Comment: What a great idea, thank you that is very helpful. All I need is an Android solution now ;)

Comment: Here is an android solution, but I just found it via google so no promises...https://github.com/okamototk/jqm-mobile-bookmark-bubble